# Explanation about arithmetico-geometric progression (AGP)

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progression

So I came across a formula that looks like:
$x_n = \alpha x_{n-1} + \beta$
Since I don't have a strong mathematical background I didn't recognize it was an AGP and as I tried to express $x_n$ with only the first term $x_0$ I concluded that this was probably the formula:
$x_n = \alpha^nx_0 + \frac{1-\alpha^n}{1-\alpha}\beta$
(I don't know if it's correct though)

I wanted to know if it was correct so after a bit of searching I finally found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence#cite_note-RHB118-1
However instead of bringing answers the article confused me:
It states that an AGP is of the form: $u_{n+1} = au_{n} + b$, fair enough, but then it says that the first term of the sequence is $t_1 = ab$ with $a$ the initial value of the arithmetic sequence and b the initial value of the geometric sequence ?
1) is there a significance in changing from $u$ to $t$ ?
2) Shouldn't it be $u_1 = au_0 + b$ ? How is this equivalent to $t_1 = ab$ ?

In short I don't understand their notation, and I don't know how to apply their formula $t_n = [a + (n-1)d]br^{n-1}$ to my problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a:=\alpha$ and $b:=\beta$. If $a=1$, then the 
equation 
$$x_n=ax_{n-1}+b \tag{1}$$
implies $x_n=x_0+bn$.

If $a\ne1$, let $y_n:=x_n-c$, so that $x_n=y_n+c$. Substituting $y_n+c$ for $x_n$ in (1), we have $y_n+c=ay_{n-1}+ac+b$, which simplifies to $y_n=ay_{n-1}$ if $c=ac+b$, that is, if we let $c:=\frac b{1-a}$. Hence, $y_n=a^n y_0$, that is, 
$$x_n=c+a^n(x_0-c). 
$$

The sequence $(t_n)$ in the linked Wikipedia article is the special case of the sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_1=ab$.

Comment: Thanks ! After playing around with your formula I managed to get back to mine (there was a typo but now it's correct) :)

Comment: Hum after thinking about it I can't figure out why c had to be defined as $\frac{b}{1-a}$... Can't we just say that $y_n = x_n - \frac{b}{a}$ so that $y_n = ay_{n-1} = a(x_{n-1} - \frac{b}{a}) = ax_{n-1} - b = x_n$ ? thus $x_n = a^ny_0 = a^n(x_0-\frac{b}{a})$ ?

Comment: @Inspi : I have added details on the choice of $c$.